# Python program to remove Nth occurrence of the given word

Tags: python-3.10

want to remove nth occurrence in string
have tried this but this, but not got required output
can anyone pls help me to solve this question

```
def remove(str,n):
    first=str[:n]
    last=str[n+1:]
    return first+last
print(remove('aabbcc',5))
```

Answer (score 0):

First off I want to complement your function, very concise and fitting for a programmer.

Now, the reason it doesn't work is because python (and most programming languages) start counting at 0. So for example

```
test = 'abcdef'
print(test[0])  # prints: a
print(test[2])  # prints: c (the third letter, because 0, 1, 2)
```

To fix your code to work as I assume you want it to work (even though your question was missing the desired output, [you'll remember next time](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) you can do

```
def remove(word, n):
    """Removes the nth character from a word, counting from 1"""
    first = word[:n-1]
    last = word[n:]
    return first+last

print(remove('abcdef', 5))  # prints: abcdf
```

Now you'll notice I made some minor changes to the code as well, it's not good practice to use `str` for variable names because `str` means something in python. It means the type string, and by using that for a variable you overwrite the other functionality and can't use it in the function. For example you might want to to

```
if (type('abc') == str):
```

to check if a variable is a string, but if you defined `str` as a variable you'll not get the desired results.

Another thing is the example string you used, `aabbcc` is not a good example string for this test, because you won't know if you removed the front or the back c for example. Which is why at first I didn't see what was wrong because both the improved function and your original one return the same thing for

```
print(remove('aabbcc', 5))  # prints: 'aabbc' in both cases
```

I also made a comment (docstring) so it is clear that this function takes numbers 1+ and not 0+ as would also be quite normal to do.

Now a very interesting thing what happens if you use your function and try `remove('abcdef', 6)` (or the new one and try `remove('abcdef', 0)`) which I leave as an exercise to figure out.